# How to fix Error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

I'm having trouble fixing this bug.

> " Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $  "

I don't understand why I got it. My code was working perfectly fine last night and I haven't made any major changes apart from changing the font of a text. I got this error when I closed android studio and reopened my project.

I tried turning off instant run but that just gave me a different error. I appreciate any help!

This is my code.

```
    package com.example.bryan.cashew;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
View.OnClickListener {

 private Button buttonSignIn;
 private EditText editTextEmail;
 private EditText editTextPassword;
 private TextView textViewSignup;


 private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

 //new
 public static final String TAG = "LOG_TAG";
 //
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

  firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

  if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
   // profile activity here
   finish();
   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
  }
  editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginTextEmail);
  editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginTextPassword);
  buttonSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
  textViewSignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp);


  buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
  textViewSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
 }


 private void userLogin() {
  final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
  final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return;

  }
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   return;
  }

  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in Please Wait");
  progressDialog.show();

  firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    //NEW STUFF CAUTION
    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmailComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
     // start the profile activity
     finish();
     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
    }
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
     Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());

     Log.w(TAG, "email: " + email + " password: " + password);
     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //END OF NEW STUFF


    /*
    GOOD STUFF DO NOT DELETE
    if(task.isSuccessful()){
        // start the profile activity
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
    }else {
       progressDialog.setMessage("Incorrect email or password");
       progressDialog.show();

    }
    */
   }
  });

 }
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
  if (view == buttonSignIn) {
   userLogin();
  }
  if (view == textViewSignup) {
   finish();
   startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
  }
 }

}




package com.example.bryan.cashew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LoginOrRegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private Button login;
 private Button register;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_or_register);
  login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogIn);
  register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);

  login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    openLogin();

   }
  });
  register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    openReg();
   }
  });
 }
 public void openReg() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }
 public void openLogin() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
 }



}




package com.example.bryan.cashew;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

 private Button buttonRegister;


 private EditText editTextEmail;

 private EditText editTextPassword;
 private EditText retypedPassword;


 private TextView textViewSignin;

 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

 public static final String TAG = "LOG_TAG";

 private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

  if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
   finish();
   startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
  }

  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

  buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

  editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

  editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
  retypedPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRetypePassword);

  textViewSignin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignin);

  buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
  textViewSignin.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 private void registerUser() {
  final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
  final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
  final String rePassword = retypedPassword.getText().toString().trim();
  if (password.length() < 6) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a password larger then 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return;
  }
  if (!password.equals(rePassword)) { // PASSWORDS ARE NOT MATCHING
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter matching passwords", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return;
  }
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
   //email is empty

   Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return;
  }
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
   //password is empty
   Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   return;
  }

  progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
  progressDialog.show();

  firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
     //user is successfully registered and logged in
     // we will start the profile activity here
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Log.w(TAG, "email: " + email + " password: " + password);
     editTextEmail.setText("");
     editTextPassword.setText("");
     progressDialog.dismiss();

     finish();
     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));

    }
   }
  });

 }
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
  if (view == buttonRegister) {
   registerUser();
  }
  if (view == textViewSignin) {
   // will open login activity
   startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
  }
 }
}



package com.example.bryan.cashew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
View.OnClickListener {

 private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
 private TextView textViewUserEmail;
 private Button buttonLogout;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

  firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

  if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
   finish();
   startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
  }

  FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();



  textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);
  textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome " + user.getEmail());
  buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);

  buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
  if (view == buttonLogout) {
   firebaseAuth.signOut();
   finish();
   startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
  }
 }
}



package com.example.bryan.cashew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
 private TextView tv;
 private ImageView iv;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


  iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

  Animation myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytransition);


  iv.startAnimation(myanim);

  final Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginOrRegisterActivity.class);

  Thread timer = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
     startActivity(i);
     finish();
    }
   }
  };

  timer.start();
 }
}
```

Comment: Fixed! For some reason android studio was messing up. I created a whole new project and imported my old one it and it fixed the problem. Hope my failure can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was creating a for loop that looped through an ArrayList object formatting each String object with regex expressions. I was able to cut down considerably on the amount of regex expressions by re-writing them in different ways. After I brought down the number of regex expression calls, I ran a clean project on Android Studio. Click where it says build on the top side menu of Android Studio, then click on clean project.